# Angularjs ui-grid sorting table according to a given column name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid version v3.0.0-rc.21-1d9f81f - 2015-05-01 and trying to sort a given grid according to a given column name. I cannot sort it externally (from javascript code), only by defining it and by clicking on the grid's headers.

Is it possible in this version to sort the grid's data according to the grid's column name via javascript code?

Comment: Are you wanting the grid to initialize with that column sorted or are you wanting to dynamically sort it at some random point down the road?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to sort it just based on a column/field before the grid is loaded, you can do so just by using the angular orderBy filter whenever your data is retrieved from the server.

```
$filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)
```

Or If you wanted to sort the grid at the initial state, you can define it in the columnDef with the sort property

```
{
            field: 'gender',
            sort: {
              direction: uiGridConstants.ASC,
              priority: 0,
            }
}
```

Take a look at this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/4qQgi76RQpYxbRgbcByX?p=preview